# How to refresh open source software pkg manager on oldish OpenSolaris?

Tags: solaris, package-management, opensolaris

I'm being presented with an [OpenSolaris](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Main/) *vps*, actually a [Solaris Container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_Containers), which is based on SXCE snv_121 and is active since mid 2007: the good old [Sun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Microsystems) days, IIRC even before the Indiana stuff!

For various reasons the system itself can't be rebuilt/upgraded but we can do whatever we want with the additional package manager on it.

My Solaris skills and especially knowledge of the free package managers ecosystem is a bit rusty so I don't know what I can actually use while keeping the somewhat oldish base system.

Currently there is pkg-get using some older [Blastwave](http://www.blastwave.org/) mirror, it has been used to install things such as Apache2, PHP, Python, Nagios. I would like to remove all the old rusty stuff and all of Blastwave, and start fresh with some newer package distribution.

Can the current Blastwave system be used on that snv_121?
Is there any better alternative still compatible with that system (eg. [OpenCSW](http://www.opencsw.org/) or anything else) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCSW packages are built on Solaris 10 (Solaris 9 support is gradually going away), and as long as your OpenSolaris maintains backward binary compatibility, packages should just work. They will be installed using pkgadd and not IPS, so you won't be able to take advantage of IPS features.

If you want to chat about any specifics, visit #opencsw on Freenode.